# How to get first value of string array in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

We have string array in XML look like:

```
<arr name="CategoryName">
   <str>Movies</str>
   <str>Movies</str>
   <str>Movies</str>
   <str>Movies</str>
   <str>Movies</str>
   <str>DVD</str>
   <str>By Languages</str>
   <str>By Title</str>
   <str>By Decades</str>
   <str>By Genre</str>
   <str>2000's</str>
   <str>Drama</str>
   <str>English</str>
   <str>QRST</str>
</arr>
```

and my output from xslt transformation look like:

```
<category>MoviesMoviesMoviesMoviesMoviesDVDBy LanguagesBy TitleBy DecadesBy Genre2000'sDramaEnglishQRST</category>
```

but i want display only first category look like:

```
<category>Movies</category>
```

And my XSLT code look like:

```
<xsl:variable name="CategoryArray" select ="arr[@name = 'CategoryName']"/>

 <xsl:for-each select="$CategoryArray">
        <category><xsl:value-of select="$CategoryArray"/></category>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

but its not working so pls give me solution for How to get first value of string array.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
$CategoryArray/str[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="$CategoryArray/str">
    <category><xsl:value-of select="."/></category>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: when we use this code its display look like: <category><category>Movies</category><category>Movies</category><category>Movies</category><category>Movies</category><category>Movies</category><category>DVD</category><category>By Languages</category><category>By Title</category><category>By Decades</category><category>By Genre</category><category>2000's</category><category>Drama</category><category>English</category><category>QRST</category></category>